# R packages - should I import the `methods` package?

Tags: r, methods, package, reference-class

I'm using `setRefClass` to create classes and since is part of the `methods` package, I presumed you need to declare this dependency as an `import`.

However, the following minimal example fails `Rcmd.exe check` when `import`ing `methods`:

```
#' @docType package
#' @import methods
A <- setRefClass("A")
```

with the following error (my package is called `Test`):

```
==> Rcmd.exe check Test_1.0.tar.gz

<Lots of checks here...>

* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Namespace dependency not required: 'methods'

See the information on DESCRIPTION files in the chapter 'Creating R
packages' of the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.

Exited with status 1.
```

So from what I can make out, it appears I'm being told to remove the `import` for `methods` and so keep hidden the package's dependency on `methods`. Is my interpretation correct and if so, why hide the dependency on `methods`?

**My setup:**

- Roxygen2 3.0.0
- R: 3.0.2 (Frisbee Sailing)
- IDE: RStudio 0.98.490
- OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: @James, but it's not always available. `Rscript` doesn't load it by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After more hunting around, I realised that in my haste I forgot to add `Imports: methods` to my `DESCRIPTION` file.